# Path and XAML controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In order to show an object on a toolbox and allow user to drag/drop it on canvas I am using following control:

```
<HeaderedItemsControl x:Key="itemABC" 
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Canvas.Left="210"
                Canvas.Top="220"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                Style="{StaticResource ABC_Style}">

</HeaderedItemsControl>
```

and

In style have defined:

```
<Style x:Key="ABC_Style" TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M10.395,0.5 L30.237,0.5 30.237,5.0359993 39.499999,5.0359993 39.499999,22.75 30.237,22.75 30.237,42.660999 39.499999,42.660999 39.499999,60.375 30.237,60.375 30.237,65 10.395,65 10.395,58.124999 0.5,58.124999 0.5,10 10.395,10 z"/>
</Style>
```

However, the problem is that HeaderdItemsControl has no Path attribute (as far as I know) so I'm wondering what other option I can have here.

In fact, I need to show a path inside a HeaderedItemsControl in XAML.

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably be setting the `Header` property to a `Path` object with that as its Data property.  If this is the solution, let me know and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: if you mean changing "Data" to "Header" then I tired it but did not affect it. It runs fine but nothing as far as content. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example works:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedItemsControl}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="ABC_Style">
            M10.395,0.5 L30.237,0.5 30.237,5.0359993 39.499999,5.0359993 39.499999,22.75 30.237,22.75 30.237,42.660999 39.499999,42.660999 39.499999,60.375 30.237,60.375 30.237,65 10.395,65 10.395,58.124999 0.5,58.124999 0.5,10 10.395,10 z
        </PathGeometry>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <HeaderedItemsControl>
            <HeaderedItemsControl.Header>
                <Path Stroke="Black" Data="{StaticResource ABC_Style}" />
            </HeaderedItemsControl.Header>
        </HeaderedItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The default style for `HeaderedItemsControl` doesn't normally actually include the header, for reasons beyond me.  Also the way you were trying to set the header to be the path data you had wasn't right, so I fixed it by defining the `PathGeometry` as a static resource and then including a `Path` using that as the `Header`.

Comment: I have used both blocks in <ResourceDictionary> due to the given design. what should change in that case?

Comment: Thanks got it work with the same technique you gave me and some minor tweaks in XAML. Thank you!!!